# Is it a good practice to do following idea based on ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, data-structures, datagridview

I am planning to show, or to say, dump a set of same objects in my application to user.

I need a control that after adding data to it, changing the data in a specific cell and row can be done programmatically.

At the moment I am using a ListView and I have populated it with my object like this:

[image]

My object is like:

```
public class TestData
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public double Force {get;set;}
public double PreTriggerVolt {get;set;}
public double PreTriggerCurr {get;set;}
public double TriggerVolt {get;set;}
public double TriggerCurr {get;set;}
public double PostTriggerVolt {get;set;}
public double PostTriggerCurr {get;set;}
}
```

The Type column is hard coded by myself in the ListView :P

I will have a lot of this in the table.

One of the problem is, sometimes, for example, after collecting the data, all or some of `TriggerVolt` values should be added/substracted by an `offset value`. You may say it is better to clear the ListView, do the changes in the object using a foreach or whatever, then recrate the ListView. But isn't there a way to directly point out to a specific row-column? Forexample I would really like something that I can name a cell and call it later. someting like:
`Cell[J6][PreTriggerVolt] == 0.01212` (just a general idea)

Another problem is sorting the data by name, greatness or ... For example if I sort the `Pin` column, the row below actual pin name can be dominant. I mean the `Force : -0.1` for example...then everything in my listview collapse!!! it will be a huge mess.

And a lot of other problems you may already know about ListView.

I want to know what is the best way to approach this goal.

Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid my knowledge at the moment cant process that! Would be nice to see some examples. To be honest I have no idea what I have to search for to learn more in this situtation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of building the listview you should look into binding the control directly to your model.  Here is a good tutorial on [Binding in WinForms](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html).  Depending on what you want to do with the data being shown a DataGrid may be a better option (especially if you want the user to be able to edit the data, even with custom controls - see [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection)).

After you have set the binding up you will need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your model class to notify the binding framework that a property has changed.

```
public class TestData:  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}

// I only included one property for simplicity.  You of course will need to do this
// for every property in the test model

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for tips. Is really I should declare the variables both in private and public mode? why not only public?

Comment: You are actually only declaring the variable once, as a private.  This is known as a "backing field".  The public get / set is a .NET property which is exposing the information (in this case publicly, but it could be private or protected). You were using what is known as an auto-property before.  When you use the syntax "property { get; set; }"  the compiler automatically creates a backing field and the get/set methods for you. We needed to manually add the NotifyPropertyChanged call to set. Here's a great overview from MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not best practice in my opinion, it's extremely fragile, sniff near the TestData Structure or the UI and it's all change time. Also the encapsulation/separation of concerns is bad.

A user Control  bound to Testdata, and then a tablelayout panel bound to a list of them them would be nicer. That way you can deal with changes to TestDataProperties in TestDataUIControl, and add / delete and refesh in the TestDataUIControlList

So twidlle with offsets is done on say a

```
BindingList<TestData>
```

The change to a TestData instance fires an event the UI control handles it and updates the relevant UI control.

Neat and tidy and nice separates TestData from control, especially if you create an Interface e.g. ITestData for it.